# How to add plugin icon to status bar using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I would like add my plugin icon to the status bar at the bottom of the screen. How would I do that? (QGIS API documentation on `statusBar()` seems to be leading to the QT docs and that site is down right now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple.

Create QToolButton class instance by calling (might be in init() section):

```
self.button = QToolButton()
```

Then in initGui() method put this lines:

```
#set default action for this button (I've chosen my second action, so that's why I put 1st index)
self.button.setDefaultAction(self.actions[1])

#add the button to statusbar
self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.button)
```

Last thing, that might be useful is adding this line to unload() method:

```
self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar().removeWidget(self.button)
```

It will prevent button to get multiple, e. g. after you reload a plugin.